# Replacement one column with a column from another file skipping the header with AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to replace a column from one file with a column from another file using AWK. The files are tab-delimited. The problem is that the second file has a header. Therefore the number of rows is not the same. I am not sure how to skip the 1st line in one file but not in the other. Any suggestions?

Thanks

For example:

Here I presented two hypothetical files (tab-delimited) where I want to replace the values from the 2nd column of **file1** with the values from the 3rd column ("NewValue") of **file2**

**file1:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "ID_1" | "U" | "Place1" |
| "ID_2" | "U" | "Place2" |

**file2:**

| "ID" | "Name" | "NewValue" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "ID_1" | "A" | "X" |
| "ID_2" | "B" | "Y" |

**Expected result:**

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "ID_1" | "X" | "Place1" |
| "ID_2" | "Y" | "Place2" |

I tried with the following code, but it didn't work.

```
awk 'NR>1 && NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {$2=a[FNR]}1' file2 file1
```

Comment: What is your column delimiter? (If it's just whitespace, unquoted `Val a` cannot be a single value).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you [edit] your question and show us the content of the real files (type the content between two sets of three back-ticks)? The tables you show raise more questions than answers. Be aware that a lot of users of this platform require detailed specifications before they can answer.

Comment: @pmf, thanks for your answer. I just edited the question to clarify. The columns are tab-delimited. I hope now the question is more clear.

Comment: @kvantour, thanks for your suggestions. I hope the question is now more clear.

Comment: So you want to change fields based on the order of lines in each file rather than by the value of the `ID` column, right?

Comment: @EdMorton, Yes, that is right. Because anyway, the order of the IDs is the same for both files.

Comment: 1) Both files are ordered by field 1? 2) They have the same ids in field 1? 3) They have the same number of lines except for the header?

Comment: @AndreWildberg, 1), 2) and 3) Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Did you try `a[NR-1]=$3` instead of `a[NR]=$0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to change fields based on the order of lines in each file rather than by the value of the `ID` column as indicated by the code in your question and as stated in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913085/replacement-one-column-with-a-column-from-another-file-skipping-the-header-with?noredirect=1#comment135589388_76913085) then using any awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[NR]=$3; next} {$2=a[FNR+1]} 1' file2 file1
"ID_1"  "X"     "Place1"
"ID_2"  "Y"     "Place2"
```

Comment: This is a Good one, cheers sir.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using only coreutil tools. `tail -n+2` chops off the first line, `paste` concatenates its inputs linewise using tabs in between, and `cut -f1,3,6` outputs the (concatenated) columns 1, 3, and 6.

```bash
tail -n+2 file2 | paste - file1 | cut -f1,3,6
```

```
"ID_1"  "X" "Place1"
"ID_2"  "Y" "Place2"
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative! I tested it, and it works with my data.